# Botocore raising OSError: [errno 14] Bad Address

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, python-3.7, botocore

My Python server is raising random `OSError: [errno 14] Bad Address` when I use pynamodb Model. This issue is happening in any of my pynamodb Models and is very rare to occur. Most of the calls will be successful.

The error is raised when botocore reads from file `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/data/dynamodb/2012-08-10/service-2.json`. I have no idea why this happens and why it is random.

I'm using **Python 3.7.3**, **Django 2.2.2**, **Pynamodb 3.3.3** and **Gunicorn 19.9.0**. I'm running the server on Docker base `python:3.7-slim` managed by Kubernetes.

Example:

```
  >>> from pynamodb.models import Model
  >>> class User(Model):
  ...     hash = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
  ...     username = UnicodeAttribute(null=True)
  ...     class Meta:
  ...         table_name = "user"
  ...         read_capacity_units = 10
  ...         write_capacity_units = 10
  ...         region = "us-west-2"
  ... 
  >>> user = User.get("valid-user-id")
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 11, in <module>
      user = User.get("valid-user-id")
  File "pynamodb/models.py", line 485, in get
    hash_key, range_key = cls._serialize_keys(hash_key, range_key)
  File "pynamodb/models.py", line 1372, in _serialize_keys
    hash_key = cls._hash_key_attribute().serialize(hash_key)
  File "pynamodb/models.py", line 1219, in _hash_key_attribute
    hash_keyname = cls._get_meta_data().hash_keyname
  File "pynamodb/models.py", line 1262, in _get_meta_data
    cls._meta_table = MetaTable(cls._get_connection().describe_table())
  File "pynamodb/connection/table.py", line 263, in describe_table
    return self.connection.describe_table(self.table_name)
  File "pynamodb/connection/base.py", line 659, in describe_table
    tbl = self.get_meta_table(table_name, refresh=True)
  File "pynamodb/connection/base.py", line 504, in get_meta_table
    data = self.dispatch(DESCRIBE_TABLE, operation_kwargs)
  File "pynamodb/connection/base.py", line 313, in dispatch
    data = self._make_api_call(operation_name, operation_kwargs)
  File "pynamodb/connection/base.py", line 341, in _make_api_call
    operation_model = self.client._service_model.operation_model(operation_name)
  File "pynamodb/connection/base.py", line 492, in client
    self._client = self.session.create_client(SERVICE_NAME, self.region, endpoint_url=self.host)
  File "botocore/session.py", line 838, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "botocore/client.py", line 79, in create_client
    service_model = self._load_service_model(service_name, api_version)
  File "botocore/client.py", line 117, in _load_service_model
    api_version=api_version)
  File "botocore/loaders.py", line 132, in _wrapper
    data = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "botocore/loaders.py", line 383, in load_service_model
    model = self.load_data(full_path)
  File "botocore/loaders.py", line 132, in _wrapper
    data = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "botocore/loaders.py", line 420, in load_data
    found = self.file_loader.load_file(possible_path)
  File "botocore/loaders.py", line 173, in load_file
    payload = fp.read().decode('utf-8')
  OSError: [Errno 14] Bad address
```

UPDATE:

This specific issue was due to a lack of memory in the pods. It happens when I integrate my server with [Scout](http://scoutapm.com). Other than this issue the rest of the app worked fine, and the error didn't suggest a memory issue. It was fixed after I raise the memory in the pod.

Comment: Are you sure that error happens when reading a file, and not while establishing a network connection? https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/issues/149 https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1194

Comment: I confirmed the file reading at the [botocore/loaders:173](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/loaders.py#L173). The var `fp` is a file object in read byte mode. I took the full path of the file from [Sentry](https://sentry.io/) event.

Comment: I, too, have encountered this error recently and have been aggressively researching into "what" it is. Errno 14 is EFAULT, which is "Buf points outside the allocated address space." Somehow the buffer to hold the read bytes has been undersized. Using "python:3.7-alpine" so this probably isn't a libC difference given you're using GlibC by virtue of 3.7-slim (debian).

Comment: I was aslo getting `OSError: [errno 14] Bad Address` from a different library, but also in a Kubernetes pod - solution to the problem was the same - more memory for pod. Thanks!

Comment: An issue very similar to this with other packages turned out to be memory related for me in a non Kubernetes setup.